# How to I remove auto generated frameset in IIS?

Tags: redirects, iis, frameset

I have a website where a redirect has been setup to use a frameset.

For example, my main website is `x-site.example`. There is a redirect setup somewhere so that `xsite.example` redirects to `x-site.example`, but it does so by creating a frameset and placing `x-site.example` within there.

This causes problems for users to login, and we do not need it to function in this fashion.

I tried writing some simple .Net code to redirect the user to `x-site.example`, but it doesn't seem to work. This leads me to believe that there is something in IIS doing the redirect before the code can execute.

How do I remove the "frameset redirect"?

Comment: *xsite.example redirects to x-site.example, but it does so by creating a frameset and placing x-site.example within there.* so it is not an HTTP redirect but some kind of messy proxying/includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in IIS that would do a frame redirect automatically.  `xsite.example` had to have been set up as website with a single HTML document or script that contains the frame.

The other possibility is that `xsite.example` is not actually hosted by you at all, you are having your DNS provider or a hosting company do the frame redirect for you.  It is very common for a registrar to do this, it is usually a checkbox when you register a domain.

Ping both `xsite.example` and `x-site.example` to get their IP addresses.  If they match, then you are hosting it yourself and need to remove the website from your IIS configuration.  If they are different IP addresses, then log into your DNS provider interface and choose a different redirection option or go to your domain name registrar to change the DNS servers to host it yourself.

Comment: I didn't realize this could be done at the DNS level. I did a quick ping and sure enough I'm getting a different IP address for the two domains. I'll do some digging into the host and come back to update.

Comment: Its not actually done at the DNS level, DNS registrars typically run simple hosting for common cases like redirects and offer them for free because they are easy to do, for domain parking they can make money on ads, and customers expect it.